# SyntaxError: missing ] after element list in jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, list, pojo

i want to assign object for StudentDetailsVo List items.

i am keep getting this error.

```
 $("#searchAtten").click(function(){
            $("#tablerows").empty();
            var sectionId=$("#selSection :selected").attr("id");
            var studid=$("#studentid").val();
            var datee = ${resultVO.monthEndDate}
            var reqD = ${resultVO.reqdEndDate}
            //I need to assign object here 
            var namem =${resultVO.studentList}
            alert("namem"+namem);
            var betweentDate=  reqD-datee;
            alert("betweentDate = "+betweentDate);
            for(var i=1;i<=datee;i++){
                alert(i);
                $("#tableRows tr").append('<th width="129" scope="col"  style="text-align: center;">'+i+'</th>'); 
            } 
             if(sectionId == undefined)
                {
                sectionId = "null";
                }
             if(studid == "")
            {
                studid = "null";
            } 
                fetch_atten(sectionId,studid);          
                });
    });
```

> i am taking this values from VO Files :

```
<% if (session.getAttribute("resultVO") != null){
     AttendanceResultVO resultVO= (AttendanceResultVO)session.getAttribute("resultVO");
         } 
%>
```

**>   my fire bug error is :

> ```
> SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
> [Break On This Error]     
>
> var namem =[com.sfmfm.vo.StudentDetailsVO@487c5f]
>
> myschool.jsp (line 53, col 43)**
> ```

Comment: the value being assigned looks like an object reference, not a value

Comment: Have a look at the **generated** JavaScript.

Comment: This is why it is important to look at the view source rather than serverside markup when debugging problems. Looking at the source, you probably would have seen the missing quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at column 43 you are at '@'. Use

```
var namem = ['com.sfmfm.vo.StudentDetailsVO@487c5f'];
```

though the text is a unusable toString, not anymore mappable on the object itself, I fear.

For minification, removing unnecessary whitespace/newlines, I would leave in semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

I wolud suggest you to do like this

```
        var datee = <%=resultVO.monthEndDate}%>;
        var reqD = <%=resultVO.reqdEndDate%>
        var namem =<%=resultVO.studentList%>
```

instead of like this

```
       var datee = ${resultVO.monthEndDate}
        var reqD = ${resultVO.reqdEndDate}
        //I need to assign object here 
        var namem =${resultVO.studentList}
```